# Why must a server know its own host-name and domain-name?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, domain

In Linux, a server can set its own `host-name` and `domain-name` through `sethostname()` and `setdomainname()`.

I just wonder, however, why must a server know its own `host-name` and `domain-name`?

To my knowledge:

1. It is enough for a server to know its own IP address, net-mask, gateway.
2. Only the DNS servers must know the `host-name` and `domain-name` of a certain server.

Any explainations?

Comment: Having a host name distinguishes it from all other systems. It's very useful for email, or for when you have to identify a system in a rack full of many systems. Email doesn't require use of IP.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, If the admin can set the host-name and domain-name arbitrarily, then how to ensure its uniqueness? And, how do other servers know the change?

Comment: You need to coordinate things with your peers if you don't want name conflicts. A domain name can only have one owner. Within a domain, you'd typically have someone or something coordinate host names (for instance, a DNS server that won't let you pick a host name that's already in use). Spammers, of course, don't care about receiving email and will happily re-use someone else's host name and domain names. And at a company, you'll find people who set up their own PC and pick a duplicate name like "gandolf", and an arbitrary unused IP address. Then the admins need to find them and fix things.

Comment: And I should have said "email doesn't require IP if the email remains local to the system or uses something like `uucp` for transmission. In the first case, you won't need a host name, but in the second case, you will."