# Domain Name as IP Abstraction vs. Domain Name as Name of Server - /etc/host{s,name} - Why?

Tags: ip, hostname, domain

A domain name is an abstraction for an IP address.  Regardless of which computer is at that IP, the domain name should point there.  So why then do we associate a domain name with a computer using the /etc/{hosts,hostname} and/or systemd's hostnamectl?  I'm definitely clueless, but this just seems wrong to me.

I'm setting up my first server at home that will be publicly accessible, using a dynamic DNS for the domain name, and so came across this hosts/hostname question.  I'm not the only one to [ask it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187032/why-must-a-server-know-its-own-host-name-and-domain-name), but that person didn't get an answer.

Comment: I don't understand why it seems wrong to you. One is obviously external to the system and one is internal. The external name can be many depending on the function, the internal name is only one. A non-networked system wouldn't even care about the external name, but might still need a name.

Comment: @muru / see below.  The docs elide the internal / external distinction, and that's the issue.  The answer I selected gets it clear to me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `/etc/hostname` (see `man 5 hostname`) you can and should set the local hostname of your server. This name may be used from software running on this server. This is just a string, which is not visible outside of the server.

In contrast, the file `/etc/hosts` is used to resolve computer names to IP addresses. You can think of this as a poor-mans DNS server. In the old times, before the Domain Name System was developed, large host files were actually sent on the computers on the Internet to map a uniform network with names.
Usually there is no need to add entries here, if you have a running DNS server and no local network with more than one server.

In order not to be dependent on a name server, you can enter your own servers and their IP addresses in `/etc/hosts`.  However, you should note that with at more servers and changing address ranges, it becomes tedious to maintain this file.

Comment: Ok, this basically makes sense.  I can leave out /etc/hosts altogether, other than maybe something pointing at 127.0.0.1 etc.  /etc/hostname I get, but I just use "Thinkpad", "ASUS", or the like.  `dnsdomainname` was particularly confusing, returning nothing without /etc/hosts being set.  The whole documentation on this elides the difference between the external name and the internal name, leaving confusion between the two.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DNS names aren't one-to-one with IP addresses, as e.g. a domain name may be only used for email, so that it only has MX records and no IP addresses. Or multiple names can point to one IP address, which is common for web servers serving more than one site with separate domain names. Also, a single domain name may point to more than one IP address, which may be useful for load-balancing.

In many of those cases it can be useful to make a difference between the public "service name" in DNS and the internal name that identifies the system and appears e.g. in logs and often the command prompt.

`/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` aren't that related really. The former is a substitute for DNS, while the latter is used to store the "internal" hostname of the system.

Comment: Thanks.  In those last two lines, you say what @Erich is saying.  I'll upvote, though I'll point out that an abstraction doesn't necessitate anything being one-to-one, so that wasn't assumed in my question.